# Does IBM ISAM/Webseal support websockets?

Tags: websocket

I am trying to find out if Ibm ISAM/Webseal supports the websocket protocol. I've tried to google for it, but with no success. Does anyone of you know if it does and if it needs any configuration to support it?

Comment: In the ibm knowledge center I found this: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSELE6_8.0.1/com.ibm.isam.doc_8.0.1/wrp_config/concept/con_comm_prot_conf.html

Unfortunately it does not look like it is supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ISAM 9.0.2.0 supports the WebSocket protocol. ISAM 9.0.2.0 should be released in November 2016.

Answer (score 1):

ISAM will happily take and deal with most packets that are HTTP formatted. WebSockets however are not supported.

Comment: Hi @ominousdw, welcome to Stack Overflow. Thank you for your contribution. In general, please try to add some (official) sources that support your statement. Also have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer